# send a mail if user does not login for a month or so in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In the first project I'm doing i have got a problem. I'm explaining it below.
first a user registers in our website while registering he will choose a reminder period like 1 month or 2 months etc.. when ever user does not log in into our site for that particular period he should get a mail saying that he need to log in
for example if user John registered in our site and chooses 2 months as reminder period. and he logs in on august 1st and did not log in for 2 months then he should get a email on October 1st saying that he need to log in. I don't know how to approach this problem. please give your ideas.

thank you

regards

vinay.J

Comment: Create a scheduler which sends mail after specified period of time.

Comment: Suggestion: treat it as two problems: 1. sending an email, 2. detecting when to send the email. For part 2 consider storing "last login" and "reminder period" with your other user data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my advice :

- Create a table containing the reminder configuration for each user
  Fields : IdUser / ReminderPeriod
- Create a windows service running each day at 2am for example. This little windows service will contain all the logic for sending emails
  It will compare the last login date of each user with the date of the day + reminded period

Comment: I'm a fresher got my training completed less than aweek. i have been given this task and there are no seniors who can guide me so i put up this question here.. i dont know whether windows sheduler could be used to send a mail on behalf of a website..

Comment: This has to be done by a service. Windows scheduler or Windows service. I will advice you to use the Windows Service written using C#. So you can do whatever you want. Your project is not a big deal dont worry and take your time to study windows services implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your problem through window service scheduler. Your scheduler will get info from db, and checks whether user logs in for 1 months, if not then fire mail to user. You can set your scheduler for any time. Say for example you set time interval 30 min. Then after every 30 min. scheduler checks for your user and send mail.

To learn window service see below links:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm working on web application.. not windows one.. can i use the same solution for web application..?

Comment: yes, you just need to create your service, and install your service, it will work. This is the only way to achieve your work.